# Determine set of subsequential limits

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose you are given a sequence $\{s_n\}$, where the odd terms $\{s_{2m+1}\}$ and the even terms $\{s_{2m}\}$ form two converging subsequences: $$s_{2m+1} \to \alpha,$$ $$s_{2m} \to \beta.$$
My intuition is that the set of subsequential limits $E$ of $\{s_n\}$ equals $\{\alpha, \beta\}$, but I’m struggling with a proof. Is there a way to pick another subsequence of $\{s_n\}$ that converges to some $\gamma \neq \alpha, \gamma \neq \beta$?

@David
If a subsequence contains finitely many odd or finitely many even terms, then in the tail it converges to either $\alpha$ or $\beta$. If a subsequence contains infinitely many odd terms and infinitely many even terms, then for no $N$ does the tail $\{s_n: n \geq N\}$ get arbitrarily close to either $\alpha$ or $\beta$. Is that the right reasoning?

Comment: Hint: any subsequence contains infinitely many even terms, or infinitely many odd terms.

Comment: @David I put my response in the question body. Thank you so much for providing a hint and not giving it away completely!

Comment: Sounds OK.$\,\!$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea.

(I). In $\Bbb R,$ one useful way of stating that $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=x$ is that for every $r>0$ the set $\{n: x_n\not \in (-r+x,r+x)\}$ is finite.

(II). In the Q, if $\alpha \ne \gamma \ne \beta$ then there exists $r>0$ such that $$(-r+\gamma,r+\gamma)\cap \;[(-r+\alpha,r+\alpha)\cup (-r+\beta,r+\beta)]=\phi.$$ For example $r=\frac {1}{2} \min (|\alpha -\gamma|, |\beta -\gamma|).$

For such $r$ we have $$\{n: s_n  \in (-r+\gamma, r+\gamma)\}\subset A \cup B$$ where $A=\{2m+1: s_{2m+1}\not \in (-r+\alpha,r+\alpha)\}$ and $B=\{2m: s_{2m}\not \in (-r+\beta,r+\beta)\}.$

By (I), $A$ and $B$ are finite, so $A\cup B$ is finite, so $\{n:s_n\in (-r+\gamma,r+\gamma)\}$ is finite. But if a subsequence of $(s_n)_n$ converged to $\gamma$ then there would be infinitely many $n$ such that $s_n\in (-r+\gamma,r+\gamma).$

Comment: Is there any reason $\mathbb{Q}$ matters for this particular problem? If $\gamma, \alpha,$ and $\beta$ are three real numbers such that $\gamma \neq \alpha$ and $\gamma \neq \beta$, then shouldn't it follow from the metric space axioms that $r>0$?

Comment: @MattAPelto .I don't follow you.  The "Q" in my answer means "Question".... & the  proposition does indeed apply to any metric space.

Comment: I see, a total misunderstanding of what you meant on my end. I probably should have paid more attention to the word "the" between the words "In" and "Q".

Comment: @MattAPelto . I've done worse myself on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you are right. Another approach:

Let $s_{k_n}\to x$. Suppose $A:=\{k_n\in \Bbb N|k_n \rm  odd\}$, $B:=\{k_n\in \Bbb N|k_n \rm  even\}$. If $A$ is infinite and $B$ finite, then $\{s_{k_n}\}_{k_n\in A}$ is a subsequence of $\{s_{2n-1}\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$, thus from uniqueness of limit and the convergence of every subsequence of a convergent sequence at the same limit, we have $s_{k_n}\to x=a$. In this case the set of subsequential limits of $\{s_n\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is $\{a,b\}$. Similarly we prove the same, if $A$ is finite and $B$ infinite. If both $A,B$ are infinite, then we combine the first two cases and we get the same result.